# Conditional Media Queries window.matchMedia

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, matchmedia

I am working with `window.matchMedia()`, and I cannot seem to get the function to apply a secondary class when a `max or min width` is reached. I've recreated the problem below with a simple font-size change.

I've read up on `matchMedia()` and I've tried this two different ways (both are included below).  Do I need to include both a min and max value in order to have the function execute? Or am I missing something within the actual structure of the function itself?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 var mq = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 700px)');
 
 if( mq.matches ) {
  $('.title').addClass('big')
 } else {
  $('.title').removeClass('big');
 }
});


/*
Second method I tried

$(function() {
 if( window.matchMedia('(max-width: 700px)').matches){
  $('.title').addClass('big')
 } else {
  $('.title').removeClass('big');
 }

});


*/
```

```css
.title {
 font-size: 20px;
}

.big {
 font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="title">This is a title</h1>
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? If you inspect the `.title` element you'll see the `.big` class added as expected (if your screen is the matching size).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is working, maybe you are expecting it to detect screen resize?
You have it bound to document.ready() so you have to refresh the page to see it.

Try it out:

- Make windows smaller than 700px, refresh
- make window larger then 700px, refresh
- Notice difference :)

In another words:

```
$(document).ready(your function)
```

Your function only executes once for each time page is loaded.

Alternatively, use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myske7t0/) and run it. Make result window larger or smaller than 700px and run it again.

**If you need to run it every time when window width resizes I would recommend binding to `window.onresize`** as I did in this [fiddle with execution on resize event](https://jsfiddle.net/vwhn1ppe/)

Notice the console.log I put there for you to see how and when it is triggered, you wanna remove it before going production ;)

Comment: Thank you so much.  Yes I was expecting it to detect the resize and add the class in the same manner as a media query.

Comment: Great answer! It helped me as well!